# Compute differences between rows in a dataframe depending on values in a column

Tags: r

Let's say I have the following data structure:

```
structure(list(treatment = c("DD", "DR", "RD", "RR", "DD", "DR", 
"RD", "RR", "DD", "DR", "RD", "RR", "DD", "DR", "RD", "RR", "DD", 
"DR", "RD", "RR", "DD", "DR", "RD", "RR", "DD", "DR", "RD", "RR", 
"DD", "DR", "RD", "RR", "DD", "DR", "RD", "RR", "DD", "DR", "RD", 
"RR", "DD", "DR", "RD", "RR", "DD", "DR", "RD", "RR", "DD", "DR", 
"RD", "RR", "DD", "DR", "RD", "RR", "DD", "DR", "RD", "RR", "DD", 
"DR", "RD", "RR", "DD", "DR", "RD", "RR", "DD", "DR", "RD", "RR", 
"DD", "DR", "RD", "RR", "DD", "DR", "RD", "RR", "DD", "DR", "RD", 
"RR", "DD", "DR", "RD", "RR", "DD", "DR", "RD", "RR", "DD", "DR", 
"RD", "RR", "DD", "DR", "RD", "RR", "DD", "DR", "RD", "RR", "DD", 
"DR", "RD", "RR", "DD", "DR", "RD", "RR", "DD", "DR", "RD", "RR", 
"DD", "DR", "RD", "RR", "DD", "DR", "RD", "RR"), correct = c(0.428571428571429, 
0.6, 0.625, 0.75, 0.757142857142857, 0.725, 0.675, 0.65, 0.971428571428571, 
0.875, 0.875, 0.875, 0.442857142857143, 0.35, 0.325, 0.425, 0.942857142857143, 
0.975, 0.925, 0.9, 0.171428571428571, 0.15, 0.175, 0.2375, 0.714285714285714, 
0.925, 0.95, 0.825, 0.957142857142857, 0.925, 0.9, 0.9125, 0.228571428571429, 
0.275, 0.275, 0.4625, 0.9, 0.8, 0.825, 0.725, 0.971428571428571, 
0.9, 0.85, 0.9375, 0.885714285714286, 0.925, 0.925, 0.95, 0.857142857142857, 
0.85, 0.85, 0.825, 0.857142857142857, 0.75, 0.75, 0.925, 0.942857142857143, 
0.925, 0.925, 0.825, 0.871428571428571, 0.8, 0.8, 0.6375, 0.957142857142857, 
0.925, 0.925, 0.85, 1, 0.925, 0.9, 0.975, 0.971428571428571, 
0.925, 0.9, 0.9375, 0.9, 0.925, 0.95, 1, 0.971428571428571, 0.95, 
0.95, 1, 0.914285714285714, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.614285714285714, 
0.775, 0.8, 0.575, 0.428571428571429, 0.575, 0.575, 0.45, 0.2, 
0.375, 0.375, 0.4625, 0.971428571428571, 0.975, 0.975, 0.975, 
0.9, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8625, 0.885714285714286, 0.9, 0.85, 0.8125, 
0.2, 0.275, 0.3, 0.2875, 0.671428571428571, 0.775, 0.8, 0.875, 
0.971428571428571, 0.95, 0.95, 1)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -124L))
```

Every four rows represents values for a given question (for different groups). I want to be able to compute (DD - DR) and (RR - RD) for every set of four rows, and store each of these in two separate columns.

I am aware of the "diff" command, which will indirectly get me what if I subset the data to include only DD and DR and another that includes only RD and RR, but I was hoping for a more explicit method.

The resulting table would have four columns (Treatment, Correct, DD-DR, and RR-RD) and the latter two columns would represent essentially grouping by the "question" (every four rows), and explicitly taking the difference between DD and DR and RR and RD.

Comment: "R is a free, open-source programming language and software environment for statistical computing, bioinformatics, visualization and general computing. Provide minimal, reproducible, representative example(s) along with the desired end result. Use dput() for data and specify all non-base packages with library calls. Do not embed pictures for data or code, use indented code blocks. For statistics questions, use http://stats.stackexchange.com. " I copied the `r` tag description for ya. If it helps to format your question

Comment: Seems like an unnecessarily aggressive comment.  The output I provided was the output provided by dput, and I specified the desired end result.  What was confusing about the question?

Comment: Desired result @Parseltongue I meant no aggression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an `id` to identify each question. So you can use the `spread` just for simplicity. After that, you can calculate `DD-DR` and`RR-RD`. Just to go back to the original format, you can use `gather`, but it is optional.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df$id <- rep(1:(nrow(df)/4), each = 4)
df %>%
  spread(key = treatment, value = correct) %>%
  mutate(DD_DR = DD-DR,
         RR_RD = RR-RD) %>%
  gather(key = treatment, value = correct, -id, -DD_DR, -RR_RD) %>%
  select(id, treatment, correct, DD_DR, RR_RD) %>%
  arrange(id) %>%
  head(10)

# A tibble: 10 x 5
      id treatment correct   DD_DR  RR_RD
   <int> <chr>       <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     1 DD          0.429 -0.171   0.125
 2     1 DR          0.6   -0.171   0.125
 3     1 RD          0.625 -0.171   0.125
 4     1 RR          0.75  -0.171   0.125
 5     2 DD          0.757  0.0321 -0.025
 6     2 DR          0.725  0.0321 -0.025
 7     2 RD          0.675  0.0321 -0.025
 8     2 RR          0.65   0.0321 -0.025
 9     3 DD          0.971  0.0964  0    
10     3 DR          0.875  0.0964  0
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the rows are always grouped adjacently, and it's always 4 per group, is this what you're looking for?

library(tidyverse)

```
dat %>%
  group_by(id = 1 + (row_number()-1) %/% 4) %>%
  mutate(dd_less_dr = 
           sum(if_else(treatment == "DD", correct, 0)) - 
           sum(if_else(treatment == "DR", correct, 0)),
         rr_less_rd =
           sum(if_else(treatment == "RR", correct, 0)) - 
           sum(if_else(treatment == "RD", correct, 0)))

# A tibble: 124 x 5
# Groups:   id [31]
   treatment correct    id dd_less_dr rr_less_rd
   <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 DD          0.429     1    -0.171       0.125
 2 DR          0.6       1    -0.171       0.125
 3 RD          0.625     1    -0.171       0.125
 4 RR          0.75      1    -0.171       0.125
 5 DD          0.757     2     0.0321     -0.025
 6 DR          0.725     2     0.0321     -0.025
 7 RD          0.675     2     0.0321     -0.025
 8 RR          0.65      2     0.0321     -0.025
...
```

Comment: Very nice and compact.  Had to accept Douglas' answer because he was slightly first and has fewer reputation.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
dat %>%
  mutate(group = ceiling(row_number()/4)) %>%
  spread(key = treatment, value = correct) %>%
  mutate(`DD-DR` = DD - DR,
         `RR - RD` = RR - RD)

# A tibble: 31 x 7
   group    DD    DR    RD    RR `DD-DR` `RR - RD`
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>
 1     1 0.429 0.6   0.625 0.75  -0.171     0.125 
 2     2 0.757 0.725 0.675 0.65   0.0321   -0.025 
 3     3 0.971 0.875 0.875 0.875  0.0964    0     
 4     4 0.443 0.35  0.325 0.425  0.0929    0.100
```

thanks to lukeA for ceiling/rownumber code.

Comment: Very clever and useful.  It technically changes the format of the data, so I'll have to accept Douglas' answer for maintaining the right shape.  But I appreciate this!